# Should I delete an old Photo library having created a new one?

Tags: photos

Have just created a new Photos folder as the old one was failing to download recent photos from the cloud.

With the new library working fine, should I delete the old (I think there are two or three) one to avoid further conflict?

Comment: As long as you have a backup, you can delete anything.

Answer (score 1):

It's unlikely that there will be any conflict as Photos will pick the new one by default. Nevertheless you will gain some disk space back if you remove the unused library.

To be on the safe side

- Verify that all the photos are in the new library in full quality
- Create a backup of the old library on an external device
- *Rename* the old library, reboot and keep using the system for 1-2 weeks
- If everything works as expected, delete the old library (but keep the backup around for a while)